# How to escape Unicode in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

So I know that the character "Latin Small Letter Sharp S" `ß` is at Unicode Point `U+00DF` and I know  how to escape this in Python 3 as a string: `\u00DF`.

However, I know that there are other unicode prefixes for the larger codepoints (such as `U+260E: Black Telephone`)

I have seen the uppercase `U` being used such as `\U00DF` and i have also seen `\x` being used.

My question is when do i use those.  For instance many emoji are just given as `U+260x`. And my thought is to use a capital `U` and fill in 12 `0s` before those digits but when do I use an `\x` and when do I know to use leading zeros (and how many)

All of this is me guessing because I can't find any documentation.

Comment: Where did you look for documentation? I found it all right here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals

Comment: Ah. I googled "escaping Unicode in Python" and looked at the 3.3.2 reference.

Answer (score 3):

The `\x` takes two hex digits.
The lower-case `\u` takes four hex digits.
The upper-case `\U` takes eight hex digits.

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code

Comment: So in my first example, why is the U+00DF escaped as `\u00DF` when it is only 2 hex digits

Comment: @Startec: `\u00DF` means exactly the same thing as `\xDF` (and the same as `\U000000DF`).

Comment: The author may have just found it more readable, maybe because there are other `\u` escapes in their codebase, or the author is just more used to them.